# Can I add dependents on my B1/B2 visa? Is there a separate fee?

Tags: b1-b2-visas, children, fees-and-charges, family

I am applying for a B1/B2 visa. I want to take my kids along on the trip to the USA? Can Iadd them as dependents on my visa application and is there a separate fee for dependents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, you can't. Everyone applies on a separate application form and pays the fee separately.

> If several members of a family or group apply for a U.S. visa, a separate DS-160 form is required for each applicant, independent of age.  Applicants have two options:
>
> - Fill out a new DS-160 form for each applicant; or
> - Fill out an initial DS-160 form and follow the instructions on the “thank you” page at the end of the form for creating a family or group application.
>
> When you select this option, certain information from the initial application, such as destination, will automatically be imported to and displayed on a new application. Please note that if you use this option you must still create an individual application for each family member or for each individual within the group.

Source: [usembassy.gov](https://de.usembassy.gov/every-applicant-must-submit-a-separate-ds-160-form/)